# php function call error when calling from another file

Tags: php

I have a function in `function.php` which outputs okay when calling inside the file, but if I include `function.php` in another file and call the function I get error.

Here is my **function.php**

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','dbuser','dbpassword','dbname');

    if( $mysqli->connect_error ) {
       die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
                . $mysqli->connect_error);
         mysqli_set_charset($mysqli,"utf8");  
    } 
    $date=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET["date"]);
    if(!empty($date)) {
        $date = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['date']);
    } else {
        $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('today'));  
    }

    function functionname() {
        global $mysqli, $date;
        $sql=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM database WHERE DateLT= '".$date."'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
            echo "somedata";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
            {

                echo "somedata";
            }
        } else {

        }
    }
    functionname()
    $mysqli->close();
/*-->*/
```

Output okay. But if i call function from **example.php** like this,

```
<?php define('ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);

include(ROOT."/function/function.php");  

functionname();?>
```

I get mysqli error.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli

Comment: Tip: you should get used to preparing your statements beforehand, your current code is vulnerable to injection. Have you checked the database connection if it's working?

Comment: database working

Comment: Why do you have `php` before `include(ROOT."/function/function.php");`?

Comment: Is that supposed to be `<?php`? But you don't have `?>` after the previous line, so you don't need to use `<?php` there.

Comment: just typing mistake. ....but error still present

Comment: Do you call `mysqli_close($mysqli)` anywhere? If you close the connection and then try to call `funcctionname()` you'll get that error.

Comment: Why are you calling the function recursively inside the `if`?

Comment: at the end of example.php i include <?php $mysqli->close();/*-->*/?> and it work. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you do

```
$mysqli->close();
```

at the end of `function.php`. You can't use the connection after you've closed it.

Take out that line.